# Создание случайных списков на основании исходного

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Есть, например, следующий список list=['a', 'b',  'c' , 'd',  'e',  'f',  'g',  'h',  'i']

Задача состоит в том, чтобы из него получить 3 новых, в каждом из которых будут содержаться 3 случайно выбранных из list, но в каждом будет иметься уникальный набор букв, что я хочу получить:

```
    list_1 =['a', 'c', 'i']
    list_2 =['b','d', 'f'] 
    list_3 = ['e','g', 'h']
```

Полазив по stackoverflow получился следующий код:

```
import random

list_1 =random.sample(list,3)
list = [x for x in list if x not in list_1]
list_2 =random.sample([x for x in list if x not in list_1],3)
list = [x for x in list if x not in list_2]
list_3 =random.sample([[x for x in list if x not in list_2],3)
list = [x for x in list if x not in list_3]
```

Первый список получаем случайным образом, далее удаляем из исходного попавшие в новый список 1.
Вновь берем уже почищенный исходный и берем в нем снова 3 случайных.... и т.д.

код рабочий и задача выполняется, однако видно явное повторение кода. Хотелось бы получать новые списки через функцию ( вероятнее всего через цикл).

Просто если дальше исходный список будет состоять, например, из 200 элементов и нужно будет сформировать 40   списков по 5 элементов, так делать уже не получится)

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Сперва перемешайте элементы списка и потом разделите перемешанный список на части?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам еще вариант с numpy. Есть подозрение, что при больших объемах данных он будет эффективнее:

```
import numpy as np
lst=['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
res = [list(x) for x in np.split(np.random.permutation(lst),3)]
```

res:

```
[['c', 'i', 'a'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['b', 'h', 'd']]
```

Если вас устраивает тип данных ndarray, то код можно еще больше оптимизировать:

```
import numpy as np
lst=['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
res = np.split(np.random.permutation(lst),3)
```

res:

```
[array(['i', 'g', 'e'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['a', 'h', 'b'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['d', 'f', 'c'], dtype='<U1')]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Выглядит очень лаконично

Answer (score 3):

Вот так можно это делать в цикле:

```
import random

list_ = ['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
lists = []
NUMBER_OF_LISTS = 3
NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_IN_LIST = 3

for i in range(NUMBER_OF_LISTS):
   a_list = random.sample(list_, NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_IN_LIST)
   list_ = [x for x in list_ if x not in a_list]
   lists.append(a_list)
```

А вот вариант с перемешиванием:

```
random.shuffle(list_)
lists = [
   list_[i*NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_IN_LIST:(i+1)*NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_IN_LIST]
   for i in range(NUMBER_OF_LISTS)
]
```

Не нужно использовать в качесвте имен переменных встроенные назнания функций, классов и т.д. Вот вы используете для хранения списка переменную и назвали ее `list`. Но уже есть стандартная функция с таким именем. Создав свою переменную вы переопределили это имя и теперь вы не сможете использовать эту стандартную функцию.

Это может привести к ошибкам в будущем, когда вы попытаетесь использовать стандартную функцию, а вместо этого будет использован ваша переменная. Хорошо, если сразу получите ошибку и догадаетесь в чем дело, но иногда это бывает сложно.

Так что лучше не использовать стандартные имена и в этом примере я изменил название переменной с `list` на `list_`.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, все намного проще!

Comment: И всё же сделайте `list_`, нужно сразу на ошибки начинающим указывать )

Comment: ```list_``` что вы подразумеваете? Я сколько не рылся по форумам, в глаза такое обозначение списков не бросалось ( если вы конечно это имели ввиду)

Comment: Добавил объяснение

Comment: @convair36 Проблема в том, что `list` - это встроенный тип Питона. Если вы называете свою переменную `list`, то вы потом не можете его использовать, например, так `list('123')` или `x = (1,2,3); y = list(x)`. Хорошим тоном считается добавлять к имени переменной `_`, если имя переменной совпадает с каким-то встроенным именем питона.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, а почему вот так код не работает list получается из df ? Причем именно через цикл не работает а перемешиванием все хорошо получается.

`df= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\МВИДЕО\progs\prog2\list.xlsx',)
list_= df['Slojnie'].values.tolist()


lists = []
NUMBER_OF_LISTS = 3
NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_IN_LIST = 2

for i in range(NUMBER_OF_LISTS):
   a_list = random.sample(list_, NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_IN_LIST)
   lists = [x for x in list_ if x not in a_list]
   lists.append(a_list)

print(lists)`

Comment: Выдает такой результат

`['a123', 'a124', 'a125', 'a126', 'a127', 'a128', 'a129', 'a130', 'a131', 'a133', 'a134', ['a135', 'a132']]`



исходный list получается таким  после преобразования из df

`['a123', 'a124', 'a125', 'a126', 'a127', 'a128', 'a129', 'a130', 'a131', 'a133', 'a134', 'a135', 'a132']`

причем если его вставить сразу списком, то все работает ( именно через цикл). Перемешиванием все хорошо работает и так

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите на ваш код и на тот что в ответе. у вас опечатка в месте, где вы удаляете элементы - не тому списку присваиваите